# HP ProBook 4530s not booting up

Tags: boot, battery

I left my computer on my desk and came back about 3 hours later. The screen wasn't showing, so I held down the power button to restart. I can't get it to turn on. The charging LED is blinking orange and blue. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The only reference to a blinking power light I can find is in the service manual and it says if it blinks amber, the battery is dead. It does not reference blinking blue AND amber though. Is there a pattern? Long, short, number of amber flashes and blue flashes etc.

One thing you could try is pulling the battery and try turning it on, see if the blinks continue, or if they cease. I'm wondering if your power brick died and the battery was exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

turn off computer/
remove cable/
press power button 10 seconds/
close screen/
plug cable in/
open screen//
press ESC and power button at the same time/

Comment: Can you elaborate on how/why this might help?